# Validate 'real' float field for digits precision

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I want to validate coordinates. Those will be stored as `real` data columns, from the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/datatype-numeric.html)

> real  4 bytes variable-precision, inexact 6 decimal digits precision

I started with the following

```
@IsNumber()
@Min(-90)
@Max(90)
/* precision check */
public latitude: number;

@IsNumber()
@Min(-180)
@Max(180)
/* precision check */
public longitude: number;
```

and would like to know how I can check for the precision of those floating numbers. It must have a 6 digits precision.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all custom stuff such as a precision the best way is to write an own custom validator where you can use a regexp or an other way to verify the input data.

The easiest way is to write a validator: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-classes

More advanced is to write an own validation decorator: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators

Answer (score 5):

The package already comes with validators for this kind of input

```
@IsLatLong()
@IsLatitude()
@IsLongitude()
```